# Trying to create a key for spatially related records using a VBA loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So what I have on my heads is an excel file with several hundred thousand rows created by a programmer with no concept of analysis / relational databases. This file essentially contains three separate tables (A, B, and C), each with their own set of fields, all mashed into one gargantuan worksheet.

Rather than assigning a key, all records for each customer are grouped together by position, and the table each row belongs to is tagged in the "Table" column as either A, B, or C. Each record will basically look like :

```
Table    Field 1   Field 2    .......
A        X         X
B        X         X
B        X         X
B        X         X
C        X         X
```

There is always a max of one A and one C per record. There is not a row for A for every record, but there is always a C. A new record always begins after each C row. VB might not be the best choice for the task but I just want to get an interim solution for the time being. This has been my attempt at the code so far (table indicator is in column B, I want to write ID to column O) :

```
Sub CreateID()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastcol As Range
Dim firstcol As Range
Dim ID As Integer

ID = 1

Set rng = Range("B4:O100")
Set firstcol = Range("B4:B100")
Set lastcol = Range("O4:O100")
For Each cell In rng
    For Each c In firstcol
        With lastcol
        lastcol.Value = ID
        End With
    If c.Value = "C" Then
        ID = ID + 1
    End If
    Next c
Next cell
End Sub
```

As you can tell if you know VBA better than I do, what this is doing is setting the value of every cell in column o to ID, and continues to change the value of every cell each time ID increments by one. Additionally, the loop does not seem to end ( I ctrl+break'd after ID shot up over 1000).

Comment: After much trial and error I figured it out:

    Sub CreateID()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim firstcol As Range
    Dim ID As Integer

    ID = 1
    counter = 1

    Set rng = Range("B4:O10")
    Set firstcol = Range("B4:B100")
    For Each c In firstcol
        rng(counter, 14) = ID
        counter = counter + 1
        If c = "C" Then
            ID = ID + 1
        End If
    Next c
    End Sub

Comment: could you convert your comment to an answer? It's possible (and even encouraged) to accept your own answer if it solves your problem. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I tried - as a new user it's telling me I need to wait 8 hours to answer my own question.  I'll go back and do that when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Back to answer my own question as promised. I am very new to VBA so I'm sure there's a more elegant / faster running way to do this and would still be interested to see what that is.

```
Sub CreateID()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim firstcol As Range
Dim ID As Integer

ID = 1
counter = 1

Set rng = Range("B4:O100")
Set firstcol = Range("B4:B100")
For Each c In firstcol
    rng(counter, 14) = ID
    counter = counter + 1
    If c = "C" Then
        ID = ID + 1
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```